# Regex - Ignore punctuation at end of string

Tags: python, regex

I am using regex to match strings, here is my code:

```
r = re.compile(r"#?%s\b" % "apple", re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE)
if r.search("I am eating an apple!"):
   print "success"
```

The "!" at the end of apple is causing it not to match... is there a way I can ignore punctuation such as ? ! at the end of the word?

Comment: can't reproduce. works fine for me.

Comment: Are you sure? Works for me.

Comment: This should work as `!` is not a word character so `\b` will split `a` and `!`

Comment: It prints "success" for me

Comment: Eek. Not sure why this isn't working for me.

Comment: Is this a simplified version of a larger piece of code? Maybe the issue is not the regex but some other part of the code.

Comment: Pro tip: use `re.escape()` to neutralize any regular-expression escapes when interpolating data into a regular expression. That way a value of `"apple\\"` will not turn `\b` into a literal `\` and `b` match..

Answer (score 1):

Your sample code works for me:  http://repl.it/J0t/5

The string formatting operator creates `#?apple\b` the `#?` is pretty useless but will allow the expression to match all the following:

```
#apple
apple
grapple
```

`apple\b` will also match the same.

If your task is to validate you have a whole word apple which is not part of another word, then I recommend something like `\bapple\b` which matches only `#apple` and `apple` from the samples above.